# FakeSMTP crashed unexpectedly

Tags: java-8, macos-high-sierra

I have been using fakeSMTP-2.0.jar successfully to do my Java development from last 4-5 years. However, from last two days, I have been repeatedly getting the following error message and the application fails to start:

```
java.lang.IllegalAccessError: class com.nilhcem.fakesmtp.FakeSMTP$1 (in unnamed module @0x12cc3010) cannot access class com.apple.eawt.Application (in module java.desktop) because module java.desktop does not export com.apple.eawt to unnamed module @0x12cc3010
```

I have always ran the application as sudo on Mac High Sierra (10.13.6) and with Java 8 (jdk1.8.0_261.jdk).

Would appreciate any insight into the issue.

Comment: You are obviously not using Java 8 anymore.

Comment: @Holger. I have default JDK17 on my machine, where I first got an error, then I set the JAVA_HOME to just run fakeSMTP and I got the same issue. On the other hand I believe the Java version should not matter much as the site of FakeSMTP expects just Java6.

Comment: The problem is that the application accesses a class that is not part of the official API. Since Java 9, the module system prevents such accesses by default. You can clearly recognize the module system as the cause, as the error message says “*module java.desktop does not export …*”. So you’re not running on Java 8. The relevance of the `JAVA_HOME` variable is a tenacious myth. Java doesn’t care for this variable at all. Some applications have custom launcher checking this variable as a convention. When you have just a jar, there obviously isn’t such a launcher.

Comment: @Holger, thanks for your input. makes sense. I'll look for alternate ways to send emails in DEV of my project.